# Forge Viewer Compass Rose

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

When viewing a model the view cube shows the orientation of the model in terms of top, bottom, left, right etc.

How would I display a compass rose graphic that would display in terms of North, South etc? Similar to Navis cube.

Note: Currently using V2.11 viewer.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean that you want to add a compass rose under the ViewCube of the Forge Viewer, right??

Comment: You can simply hide the view cube: viewer.showViewCubeUI(false). And implement your own custom control that you overlay on top of the viewer area. It, of course, requires a bit of work ...

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2019-11-08:** This whish list item, `LMV-2837`, has been implemented by our engineering team now. You can see the compass under the ViewCube with the viewer v7.6 by default!! Here is the snapshot:

[image]

=============

After v2.16, viewer has capability to display labeled axis lines, see [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v216) for more detail. But there still is no API available to add custom graphic to the viewer `ViewCube` in my experience unfortunately, in part because there has been no known user interest.

However, we are interested in your need for displaying custom graphic with the `ViewCube` and what benefits it would have for you. Could you share with us, please? If it cannot be shared publicly, you can sent those information to `forge.help@autodesk.com`.

**P.S. Please don't sent any sensitive data or information of yours and your company to us.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason for display of compass rose is based on a user request. The source solution is Navis and it shows the directions of compass underneath the cube. In this case the plant size is measured in km not metres and consists of very complicated piping. The user found it hard to orient themselves using the forge viewer when trying to compare the model to the actual piping without easily seeing in what direction they where viewing the model.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explains, we have logged this issue in our internal case system as `LMV-2837` for the dev team to allocate time to investigate. There is no ETA for this request, you can send `LMV-2837` to `forge.help@autodesk.com` to track updates anytime in the future.