# How to display directions in Viewer Cube in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: jquery, autodesk-forge

I have a simple question regarding the Autodesk Forge Viewer 3D. All the Models have a ViewCube at the top right of the Viewer which makes it easy to orbit around the model. Suppose if a user is dealing with a model which is related to a real life structure or a building then shouldn't there be a direction indicator for the ViewCube? If there is such option, how to enable or code for it in Autodesk Forge Viewer.

I have attached a screen shot of a ViewCube taken form Autodesk Design Review. I need a similar ViewCube in Autodesk Forge Viewer as well.

[image: Image Of ViewCube in Autodesk Design Review]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911488/forge-viewer-compass-rose/45912221#45912221) and wishlist item logged as `LMV-2837`, but it hasn't been implemented yet so far. Unfortunately, `ViewCube` API doesn't be exposed, so you cannot either make it yourself. Apologizing for any inconvenience caused.

Currently, there is a function `GuiViewer3D#showViewCubeTriad` for showing the three base axis (XYZ) on the bottom of the `ViewCube`.

```
viewer.showViewCubeTriad( true );
```

Comment: Thank You for the reply @Eason Kang